# Таблица пользователей

Tags: html

есть бд в которой список пользователей, на страницу выводится в виде таблицы список пользователей, хочу добавить функцию выбора нескольних пользователей и дальше их удалить/заблокировать как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот тогда форма

```
<form action="some.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delOrUpdate" value="true">
    <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Получаешь по post массив из id, после цикл, который генерериут запрос и условие

Не хочешь формой

Создаешь блок где чекбоксы, выделяешь активные, jquery вытягивывываешь те, которые активные, ajax отправляет запрос на php страничку и цикл

Comment: запросы в бд понятно как делать, пишу на php, просто вывод из бд я делаю  а как связать чекбокс на странице с определённой записью в бд?

Comment: к примеру в chekbox есть value при запросе из бд вставляешь туда его id, после в поле form отправит все id, в соотвствие делаешь с ними все что хочешь